# Download latest results if run was successful

Tags: apify

I would like to know, how is it possible to download latest results from Apify with curl if run was successful.

Currently I am using this:

```
curl "https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/SECRET/runs/last/dataset/items?token=SECRET&format=csv&clean=1" -o latest-result.csv
```

It's pretty dumb at this moment, it is downloading result even when crawler failed and including error in the output.

Ideal would be to check if actor was finished and when succeeded, download the clean results.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another query parameter to your query: `status=SUCCEEDED`. It will filter the actor runs based on their status.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can filter the status in the URL.

`curl "https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/SECRET/runs/last/dataset/items?token=SECRET&format=csv&clean=1&status=SUCCEEDED" -o latest-result.csv`